# Can dynamic programming problems always be represented as DAG

Tags: dynamic-programming

I am trying to draw a DAG for Longest Increasing Subsequence {3,2,6,4,5,1} but cannot break this into a DAG structure.

Is it possible to represent this in a tree like structure?

Comment: Yes. DP works only on DAGs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, the answer to the actual question in the title is, "No, not all DP programs can be reduced to DAGs."

Reducing a DP to a DAG is one of my favorite tricks, and when it works, it often gives me key insights into the problem, so I find it always worth trying.  But I have encountered some that seem to require at least hypergraphs, and [this paper](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/C08-5001) and related research seems to bear that out.

This might be an appropriate question for [the CS Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/), meaning the abstract question about graph reduction, not the specific question about longest increasing subsequence.

Comment: A hypergraph could be directed and acyclic as well.

Comment: Sure.  But then it's not a directed acyclic graph, it's a directed acyclic hypergraph, except in the special case where all the hyperedges share only two nodes, i.e., the special case where the hypergraph is just a graph.

Comment: Nevertheless every directed acyclic hypergraph can be transformed to a DAG.

Comment: Hmmm.  It's true that any hypergraph can be converted to a graph, I had forgotten that.  Is it known that any DAH can be converted to a DAG?  That would clinch it, and make my currently accepted answer wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming following Sequence, S  = {3,2,6,4,5,1,7,8} and R = root node. Your tree or DAG will look like

```
              R
      3    2     4    1
           6     5    7
                      8
```

And your result is the longest path (from root to the node with the maximum depth) in the tree (result = {r,1,7,8}).

The result above show the longest increasing **sequence** in S. The Tree for the longest increasing **subsequence** in S look as follows

```
              R
   3   2   6   4   5   1   7   8
   6   4   7   5   7   7   8  
   7   5   8   7   8   8      
   8   7       8   
       8
```

And again the result is the longest path (from root to the node with the maximum depth) in the tree (result = {r,2,4,5,7,8}).

Comment: Hi on what basis did you choose 3    2    4    1

Comment: Sequentially, 3 next 2 -> not higher -> create new branch with 2 next 6 -> higher -> go on -> 4 -> not higher ...

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question should be **YES**.

I'd like to cite the following from here: [The Soul of  Dynamic Programming
Formulations    and Implementations](https://cs.nyu.edu/courses/spring16/CSCI-UA.0480-004/lecture_11.pdf).

> A DP  must    have    a   corresponding   DAG (most   of  the time    implicit), otherwise    we  cannot  find    a   valid   order   for computation.

For your case, Longest Increasing Subsequence can be represented as some DAG like the following:

[image]

The task is amount to finding the longest path in that DAG. For more information please refer to section 6.2 of [Algorithms, Dynamic programming](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Evazirani/algorithms/chap6.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is possible to represent longest Increasing DP Problem as DAG.
[image]

The solution is to find the longest path ( a path that contains maximum nodes) from every node to the last node possible for that particular node.
Here, S is the starting node, E is the ending node and C is count of nodes between S and E.
S E C
3      5        3
2      5        3
6      6        1
4      5        2
5      5        1
1      1        1

so the answer is 3 and it is very easy to generate solution as we have to traverse the nodes only.
I think it might help you.
Reference: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/lecture-videos/lecture-20-dynamic-programming-ii-text-justification-blackjack/